# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OpenSDK"

Tags: ios, xcode

- M2 arm64
- Xcode 14.3.1

build fail
--ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

`ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/ebuy-ronin/dev/ebuy_ios/New Group' ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/ebuy-ronin/dev/ebuy_ios/New Group' ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/ebuy-ronin/dev/ebuy_ios/OpenSDK.framework/OpenSDK, file is     universal (armv7,arm64) but does not contain the x86_64 architecture: /Users/ebuy- ronin/dev/ebuy_ios/OpenSDK.framework/OpenSDK Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OpenSDK", referenced from: objc-class-ref in MpayMpayMessageHandler.o objc-class-ref in MainViewController.o objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEflz.png)